# Manually Update authz on CollabNet Subversion Edge Server

Tags: svn, authz, subversion-edge

I have a repository set up on CollabNet Subversion Edge 3.1.0.

I want to use LDAP groups with different permissions to authenticate against my repository.

Of course, Apache's authz is unaware of LDAP groups. My strategy is to have a script that automatically updates the authz for the repository automatically on a nightly basis, as described in [Using LDAP Groups With Subversion's Authz File](http://www.thoughtspark.org/node/26).

However, authz is ignored by CollabNet's web server, and there seems to be a file hidden somewhere that can only be updated through the Collabnet admin interface.

Is there any way I can do this "manually" (i.e. finding that file and setting permissions so that a system user can run the script?)

For the record, the script I'm going to be using is a hand-rolled Windows PowerShell script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We recommend people use this script all the time.  The authz file is not hidden.  It is named svn_access_file and located in the Subversion Edge data folder.  Just have your script update that file.

Comment: In particular, `csvn\data\conf\svn_access_file`. Thanks! For reference of anyone else stumbling across this post, can you add a link to the official documentation where this file and integration with that script are discussed to your answer?